# write content to notepad in specified format with separator

Tags: vb.net, file-io

i want to create a notepad in this format

```
100001|10001|1001|91|9942321400|MR|Hari|Q|PUBLIC|249 MUNDON ROAD|MALDON|FL|44|TN|NO_PROVINCE|600004|IN|M|27304|9942321400|test@test.com|nothing|COMMENTS|1|Southeast
100001|10001|1001|91|9865015695|MR|Hari|Q|PUBLIC|249 MUNDON ROAD|MALDON|FL|44|TN|NO_PROVINCE|600004|IN|M|27304|9942321400|test@test.com|nothing|COMMENTS|1|Southeast
100001|10001|1001|91|9894825469|MR|Hari|Q|PUBLIC|249 MUNDON ROAD|MALDON|FL|44|TN|NO_PROVINCE|600004|IN|M|27304|9942321400|test@test.com|nothing|COMMENTS|1|Southeast
```

am using vb.net,in the above format except phone number remaining values are same.and it would be written in to the notepad with pipeline separator. 
        phone number values are recieved from dataset and store it in a variable . with in looping am use stream writer statement. but am not able to get the output. please help me to do this?  am new to vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that to write your file.

Import System.IO and add that routine. The Path should be the complete path including the file name and extension of the file you want to generate. If you change False to True it will append the text at the final of the file if you write it again, with false it overwrite it.

```
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path, False, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    for each ...
        writer.writeLine(var1+"|"+var2...)
    Next
    writer.Close()

    End Using
```

Comment: how did we close the writer with in the loop.

Comment: if we close the writer with in the loop means if the control goes to second time to the loop we cant able to write the values in the notepad

Comment: i just wrote the for each as an example, but close the writer after the for each finishes, i will edit that.

Comment: I've edited as well the command writer.writeLine, if you use writeLine it will add a line break at the final and you will start a new line in the next loop. With just write it continues at the same line. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: am getting error in writer.writeline statement ,Operator '+' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.EventArgs'.

Comment: Can you write the complete error and the writeLine argument you're writting? Is the visual studio giving you a solution for this error?

Comment: am the statement in below like this sw.WriteLine(a & "|" & b & "|" & c ) but am getting error

Comment: It's not important if you're using + or &, but, if a b and c are not strings you should apply a.ToString()